# Firefox WebDriver crashes when computer is idle too long

Tags: firefox, crash, arch-linux, awesome-wm

I'm using a Python script and Selenium to run some tests using the Firefox Web Driver on an Arch Linux system running Awesome WM.

These tests take a long time, so I don't want to sit at the computer while they run. I had been running these tests in the same manner for about 2 weeks with no issues, and then after an Arch Linux system update (pacman -Syu) I am having an issue.

The problem is that when I come back (after say an hour or 2) the web driver has often crashed at a seemingly random spot in the tests. If I re-start the tests, it will get past the spot where it was frozen. I have never actually seen it stop, only returned to see a web driver that is not responding. The web driver window shows only a title and nothing in the body of the browser.

I think that it may be happening because my computer is entering an idle state, but it doesn't ALWAYS happen. If I sit here and wait for the screen to go black then move the mouse shortly after, the web driver usually still running.

Is there a chance my screen is turning off, and then later entering an idle state that would stop the web driver from functioning properly?

I have tried modifying `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to set `IdleAction=ignore` but the screen still goes black after some time, and I still end up with the problem if I leave for a while. I have thought about rolling back parts of my system, but I'm not sure what specifically I should be rolling back.

Is there anything else I should check that might be causing processes to stop working on idle?

Thanks!